# VC2019: Compiler Bug, std::pair Bug or Obscure Feature

Tags: c++, c++17, visual-c++-2019

The code below crashes the application or prints gibberish. If the initialization of the base class is replaced with `str_int{ string{V}, 0}` then it works fine. Seems to work fine with some online compilers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

using str_int = pair<string, int>;

template< const char* V > 
struct C : public str_int
{
  C() : str_int{ V, 0} {}
};

constexpr const char str[] = "abc";

int main()
{
  // works fine
  str_int si{str, 0};
  cout << si.first;

  // crashes the application or prints gibberish
  C<str> c;
  cout << c.first;
}
```

Comment: Rare (indeed) though such things are, I would venture to suggest it's a bug in the MSVC compiler (clang-cl in Visual Studio has no problem with your code).

Comment: Testing with older versions of MSVC (v19.16) I had the add the `<string>` header does adding this header affect your tests ?

Comment: @RichardCritten In my VS (16.9.2), adding the `<string>` header doesn't fix the problem (although it's a good spot).

Comment: @RichardCritten Adding `<string>` has no effect on my version - VS16.7.5.

Comment: This is [CWG2043](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#2043)/[CWG2401](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#2401); the code is valid as of C++20.

Comment: It does not have anything to do with `std::pair` or `std::string`, I've reported a reduced version: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/bad-code-generation-on-passing-template-const-char/1534999

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug in the compiler, I've reported it based on the reduced version of the repro in the question couple of years ago. (I've reduced it to avoid STL usage, clean compiler repros are better for such cases.)

It is fixed in the current Visual Studio version.

See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/bad-code-generation-on-passing-template-/1534999

Comment: Nice followup :thumbsup: